# sed command for searching multiple strings and replace one of the string

Tags: sed

I would need to edit a param value, in a specific block. Can you help with the sed command in this. I know to do this with a perl script, but i need  in one single command

My file looks like this

```
Block 1
   Param1=val1
   Param2=val2
   .
   .

Block 2
   Param1=val1
   Param2=val2
   .
   .

Block 3
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is your expect output ?

Comment: Replace parameter value like Param1=modifiedval1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of sed's address: `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` to handle only one "block". For example, if you just want to change `Param1` in `Block 1`:

```
sed -r '/^Block 1/,/^Block 2/s/(\s*Param1=).*/\1NEW/' file
```

If you have many blocks, you can use `^Block 1$` or `^Block 1\s*$`. This won't get mess with for example: `Block 120`

Comment: Kent, I need to modify the parameter value in one of the blocks only. I tried this sed -r '/^Block 1/s/(\s*Param1=.*)/\1Param1=newvalue/' file. It did not edit. Am I missing anything

Comment: @cms my cmd will output the result (with param1 changed). If you want to change the file, add `-i` option to your gnu sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '/^Block/h;G;s/(Param1=)\S+(.*\nBlock 2)$/\1newval\2/;P;d' file
```

Store the current block in the hold space and append the block variable to each line of the file. Substitute a new parameter value if there is a match on the parameter and the block variable. Print every line and delete the block variable.

N.B. the solution above replaces parameter 1 in block 2, tailor the solution for your needs.